# Can anyone reccomend a 3D modeling software?

Tags: 3d, vector-graphics, modeling

Can anyone recommend a 3D modeling software. My goal is to create a 3D model, be able to take a photograph of the model from different angles and different positions (must have rigging), save those photos.

Preferably it would be simple (I've tried blender but the amount of features absolutely confuses me) and preferably it would be widely used so I can download other peoples models and work with them, as i'm not good at creating them.

The reason I need all this is that each photo will be edited to take the background out and that model will be used as a 2d graphic, so I plan to take many photos of the same models in different positions to create the animation. Being able to keep the shadows of the models in the final render is super important, so lighting is a must.

any help is appreciated.